# What is Philip asking for in John 14:8?

Tags: john, theophany

[When Philip asks Jesus](http://esv.to/John14.8), "Lord, show us the Father, and we will be content," what is he asking for? Obviously his categories were mistaken, because the answer to his request was standing right before him; but what was he anticipating Jesus would do? Was his request along the same lines as Moses' request, "Now show me your glory", in [Exodus 33:18](http://esv.to/Exo33.18)? Or was Philip hoping that they would be caught up into heaven to see the Father? Something else?

Comment: +1 Good question. I'll be curious to see anyone can explain his perspective, which seems to be one of utter confusion.

Comment: Sincerly I don't know.
But I hope you find the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Philip wanted to see The Father with his own eyes, just as he sees the Son of God with his own eyes (Son of God == Jesus). To put it another way, he wanted to see The Father in physical form.

The 2 previous verses gives us a clue as to what triggered Philip to ask this question.

```
 - verse 6: Jesus states "no one comes to the Father except through me"
 - verse 7: Jesus states "you do know him and have seen him"
```

verse 6: Philip's train of though might have been "If Jesus can show me the Father, then why not ask?  This would clarify so many things for me."

verse 7: Philip's train of thought might have been "That's confusing.  How have I seen the Father? But if Jesus is right, then I want to see the Father [again]".